# Illegal instruction upon operating on an array

Tags: c, arrays

Okay so I am trying to make a histogram from a three dimensional array of int in c.
Here is the line where I edit the array;

```
buckets[(int)floor(x/splits)][(int)floor(y/splits)][(int)floor(z/splits)]++;
```

x, y, z were generated earlier in the program (this is in a loop) splits was asked as input from the user. Then I try to put this data into a histogram and the compiler is giving me an illegal instruction.

```
histogram[(int)buckets[i][j][k]]++;
```

I am pretty sure it is here because I put print statements in the program which worked until this point but not afterwords. Here is all of the relavent code.

```
    ff=fopen(fname,"r");
int buckets[split][split][split];
splits = (double) 1/split;
for(i=0; i<split; i++){
    fscanf(ff,"%lf",&x);
    fscanf(ff,"%lf",&y);
    fscanf(ff,"%lf",&z);
    buckets[(int)floor(x/splits)][(int)floor(y/splits)][(int)floor(z/splits)]++;    
    fclose(ff);  
}
int histogram[10];
for (i=0; i<split; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<split; j++){
        for(k=0;k<split;k++){
            histogram[(int)buckets[i][j][k]]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most likely cause is that the value of `buckets[i][j][k]` is greater than the length of the `histogram` array.  If that's not the problem, then please edit your question to include a minimal self-contained test-case (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: Compilers don't generate illegal instructions.  Blowing the stack with a buffer overflow and causing a crash when the function returns is the common explanation.  Use a debugger and update your question with what you found out.

Comment: Using `printf` may not always give you the exact line that your program failed on because you have to make sure that the buffer is flushed by printing `\n` or calling `fflush(stdout)`. To find the problematic line, you could instead run your program with valgrind.

Comment: What is split equal to?  Is it set at runtime or a const value?

Comment: There were two problems with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your array:

```
int buckets[split][split][split];
```

You do not initialize it with something like:

`memset(buckets, 0x00, sizeof(int) * split * split * split);`

So buckets has unknown values in it.  You then increment these numbers, but when you do:

`histogram[(int)buckets[i][j][k]]++;`

`buckets[i][j][k]` could be equal to anything.  Solution is to add the memset() after the array declaration.

Comment: There were two problems with the code
1) i needed to initialize the array to zero values
Thanks for the new method I used a for loop instead.
2) I used fclose() within the for loop so it kept reopening and started from the begining

Answer (score 0):

Please share the actual values of the variables during run-time (using gdb) - split, x, y, z and splits.

If you see the correct values initially and suddenly seeing an abnormality, then you may be hitting a stack overflow. So try using dynamic memory allocation (which uses heap). Please try to use valgrind to detect any memory leaks.